# Useless SBCL on my linux VPS: ensure_space: failed to allocate n bytes

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

I can not run SBCL on my VPS:

```
mmap: wanted 1040384 bytes at 0x20000000, actually mapped at 0x715fa2145000
ensure_space: failed to allocate 1040384 bytes at 0x20000000
(hint: Try "ulimit -a"; maybe you should increase memory limits.)
```

A search gives me:

- http://compgroups.net/comp.lang.lisp/useless-sbcl-on-win32-memory-problem/702748 => using `sbcl --dynamic-space-size 880` doesn't work either.
- https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=474402 => the OP enlarges its swap to 20Go. Crazy. And they say it's fixed in SBCL 1.1.

I have 510MB of free swap, 3GB of free RAM.

**update**: `SBCL 1.2.4.debian`, Debian 8.2.

Is there a solution to this problem ?

and btw, how do *you* deploy lisp apps ?

Thanks !

ps: I can not use Roswell to install other implementations (it is based on SBCL). Workarounds would be to use CCL ([CCL Debian package](http://mr.gy/blog/clozure-cl-deb.html)) or Docker ([daewok/lisp-devel](https://github.com/daewok/lisp-devel-docker)).

Comment: Which version of SBCL are you trying to run?  Which GNU/Linux distribution and version are you using?

Comment: of course… sbcl 1.2.4, Debian 8.2.

Comment: I'll add it's an [OVH Kimsufi](http://www.kimsufi.com) server.

Comment: You might try the version from debian testing https://packages.debian.org/buster/sbcl

Comment: @siehe-falz thanks, but that's of no help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to disable ASLR globally on the VPS :

```
sudo bash -c "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space"
```

After that SBCL should run fine.